# mysql optimize or simplify SQL statements

Tags: mysql

mysql table is

intersection  record basic information

relation      record intersection and roadside relation, intersection and intersection relation

code

```
SELECT  c.*,
        d.obj_name as end_name,
        e.obj_name as start_name
    from ( SELECT  a.source_key as start_key,
                   b.source_key as end_key,
                   a.target_key as roadside_key
            FROM ( SELECT  *
                    FROM  `brelation`
                    WHERE  source_key='c1_VbFljpol'
                      and  target_concept='roadside'
                      and  rel_number=1
                 ) as a
            JOIN ( SELECT  *
                    FROM  `brelation`
                    WHERE  source_key in (
                        SELECT  target_key
                            FROM  `brelation`
                            WHERE  source_key='c1_VbFljpol'
                              and  target_concept='node'
                          )
                      and  target_concept='roadside边'
                      and  rel_number=2
                 ) as b ON a.target_key=b.target_key 
         ) as c
    JOIN  bintersection as d  ON c.end_key=d.obj_key
    JOIN  bintersection as e  ON c.start_key=e.obj_key
```

final reslut

```
start_key   start_name end_key      roadside_key end_name
c1_VbFljpol aaaa       c1_hKwEo6JZ  c3_G2rSzUIK  bbbb
c1_VbFljpol aaaa       c1_gDUWuB4V  c3_YtKWzPy0  cccc
c1_VbFljpol aaaa       c1_uayODvZz  c3_SMz1WGl0  dddd
```

Comment: You've gone too minimal. What is the current behavior with this? How are the tables defined? What does `explain` show? Is the return correct just taking too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow... what a mess of a query..  However, when rewritten, is this what you are ultimately looking for?

```
SELECT 
        br.source_key Start_Key,
        br2.source_key End_Key,
        br.target_key Roadside_Key,
        bi2.obj_name as end_name,
        bi.obj_name as start_name 
    FROM 
        brelation br
            JOIN bintersection as bi
                ON br.source_key = bi.obj_key

            JOIN brelation br2
                on br.target_key = br2.target_key
                AND br.source_key = br2.source_key
                AND br2.target_concept = 'node'
                AND br2.rel_number = 2

                JOIN bintersection as bi2
                    ON br2.source_key = bi2.obj_key
    WHERE
            br.source_key = 'c1_VbFljpol' 
        and br.target_concept = 'roadside' 
        and br.rel_number = 1
```

Your inner sub-select queries creating alias A and B are targeting the same source, but "rel_number" = 1 and Roadside vs "rel_number" = 2 and Node.  So just join those as they are.  Now, your BIntersection tables.  I am using those with respective aliases as well from BR/BI to BR2/BI2 respectively for the start and end context.

You dont need to specificy the source key twice since whatever is in the main table is the basis joining to the second instance BR2 by same key value.

I THINK this is what you are looking for.

**FEEDBACK**

Nothing was mentioned about performance... For that and knowing that the query provided is cleaner and is doing what you need, now we can look at indexes.  For this query, I would suggest a proper multi-column index on the tables as follows.

```
table         Index
brelation     (Source_Key, Target_Concept, Rel_Number)
bintersection (Obj_Key, obj_name)
```

Comment: thansk,readability improved, but the speed did not improve much, it may be that the amount of data is not large enough

Comment: @xin.chen, see feedback in answer for proper indexes for performance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `*` with just the columns you need.

Change `source_key in ( SELECT ... )` into a `JOIN` or `EXISTS ( SELECT 1 ...)`

If you are not using MySQL 8.0, this construct is likely to be slow:

```
FROM ( SELECT ... ) a
JOIN ( SELECT ... ) b ON ...
```

(I don't understand the query will enough to suggest a rewrite.)

Indexes that may help:

```
bintersection:  INDEX(obj_key,  obj_name)
brelation:  INDEX(source_key, target_concept, rel_number,  target_key)
brelation:  INDEX(target_concept, rel_number,  source_key)
brelation:  INDEX(source_key, target_concept)
```

These may help DRapp's rewrite may need this index, too:

```
brelation:  INDEX(target_key,  source_key, target_concept, rel_number)
```